# use oocharts plug in to my webpage by getting google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

May I know what is the problem? I cant display anything out from the oocharts file. I have set up the API key and get the profile ID from Google Analytic but seem not display out too. Is it there id something I have to add?

```
<div data-oochart="bar" data-oochart-start-date="30d" data-oochart-metrics="ga:visits,Visits,ga:newVisits,New Visits" data-oochart-dimension="ga:continent" data-oochart-profile="{{PROFILE ID}}"></div>

    <script src="../oocharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function(){

            oo.setAPIKey("{{API KEY}}");

            oo.load(function(){

                var bar = new oo.Bar("{{PROFILE ID}}", "30d");

                bar.addMetric("ga:visits", "Visits");

                bar.addMetric("ga:newVisits", "New Visits");

                bar.setDimension("ga:continent");

                bar.draw('chart');

            });
        };

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually trying to draw two charts right now. OOcharts has an HTML attribute API and a JS API. The top div is using the HTML API, while your JS code is using the JS API. To just use the HTML attribute API, you can try:

```
<div data-oochart="bar" data-oochart-start-date="30d" data-oochart-metrics="ga:visits,Visits,ga:newVisits,New Visits" data-oochart-dimension="ga:continent" data-oochart-profile="{{PROFILE ID}}"></div>

<script src="../oocharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){

        oo.setAPIKey("{{API KEY}}");

        oo.load();
    };

</script>
```

You are replacing the {{PROFILE_ID}} and {{API_KEY}} with your own information, correct? Once you have done this, open up the web console and make sure an outgoing request is being sent to the OOcharts API.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:
At the oo.setAPIKey function you use the API key provided by the Oocharts Mission Control. At the oo.Bar you use just the number of your profile id, not ga: and then the number. And of course at the bar.draw('chart') you replace 'chart' with 'bar'.

Hope this will prevent someone (like me) from throwing his head to the wall ;)...